# LocalConfiguration.current call in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've seen a few times where `LocalConfiguration.current` is called, but the return value is not consumed. For instance, in the [Now in Android sample app](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid):

```
@Composable
fun calculateWindowSizeClass(activity: Activity): WindowSizeClass {

    LocalConfiguration.current. // What are we doing here?

    ... // rest of code not shown 

    return WindowSizeClass.calculateFromSize(size)
}
```

What is the purpose of this `LocalConfiguration.current` call?

Comment: It causes the composable to be recomposed if the configuration changes. See https://jetc.dev/slack/2022-02-13-why-resources-strange.html for more.

Comment: I see this method is re-called every orientation change (e.g., portrait --> landscape) but that's because `MainActivity.onCreate` is recalled. If another configuration change happens  that doesn't cause onCreate to be called again (e.g. hardkeyboard connected), then will that cause  `calculateWindowSizeClass` to be called again?

Comment: My understanding is that yes, it will be called again. Many Google Compose engineers are recommending that developers opt out of configuration changes (via `android:configChanges` in the `<activity>` in the manifest), and `LocalConfiguration` should get updated via `onConfigurationChanged()` callbacks as well.